# RegEx-Scala (facing issue while matching pattern to separate token)

Tags: regex

**I am writing regex to extract token from below sentence, like "(" is LEFT_BRACKET, "is" is IS, "teddy" is Attribute(TEDDY,INT), "or" is "OR", "NULL" is NULL, ")" is RIGHT_BRACKET. But somehow the last word NULL is coming as Attribute(NULL) instead of separate token NULL. If I give space after NULL then only it comes as token otherwise it is matched with Attribute. Please help how to resolve this problem.**

```
 **Sentence is**   (data is teddy or is NULL)

    **The corresponding regex is as follows:**

     <b>1. regex to resolve ")"</b>
 case class LEFT_BRACKET() extends Token {
      override def pattern: Parser[Token] = regex("\\(".r) ^^ (_ => LEFT_BRACKET)
    }
     <b>2. regex to resolve "is"</b> 
 case class IS() extends Token {
      override def pattern: Parser[Token] = regex("(?i)^is ".r) ^^ (_ => IS)
    }
     <b>3. regex to resolve "teddy"</b>   
    def attrR = regex("[\\{\\{]*[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_.}}]*[\\}\\}]*".r)
    def attribute: Parser[ATTRIBUTE] = (attrR) ^^ (attr => {
    val dTYPE: TYPE = TYPE.STRING
    ATTRIBUTE(attr, dTYPE)
  })
      <b>4. regex to resolve "or"</b>  
 case class OR() extends Token {
      override def pattern: Parser[Token] = regex("(?i)^is ".r) ^^ (_ => OR)
    }
       <b>5. regex to resolve "null"</b> 
 case class NULL() extends Token {
      override def pattern: Parser[Token] = regex("(?i)^null ".r) ^^ (_ => NULL)
    }

**Above case classes are being called with the help of object.**
```

Comment: This is a very confusing/badly worded question.

What are you trying to achieve with regex?

Do you want it to find all instances of `(`, `)`, `is`, `teddy`, `or`, and `null`?

Comment: You could try this online tool, i might make your iteration loop a bit faster:

https://regex101.com/

Comment: The regex which is written for Attribute (3) should not accept null. Null should be accepted by regex which is written for it (5).